# Visual Studio Code adding 'prefix0' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have recently switch from Android Studio to VS Code to work on my Flutter projects but I have an issue with it.

VS Code keeps adding "prefix0." before all classes as soon as I am using auto-completion and I didn't find a way to get rid of it.

I have seen that some VS extensions for CSS can auto-prefix some parts of code but I do not have any CSS extensions.

Thanks

Comment: When I came across this issue it was because I had classes with the same name. It does this to avoid conflicts

Comment: Oh yes thanks ! I had the same ```import``` twice.

Comment: Great since that was the problem I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by there being one or more duplicates of class names. Check that you do not have classes with the same name imported that may conflict with each other.

Comment: That's usually not the issue. It's a bug in Dart Code, where it'll import the same classes/functions again, with a prefix

Comment: Ah I see, have you come across a discussion about the issue? I couldn't see anything on github.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in Dart Code that happened because it failed to understand another import already exported the class used.

A typical example is, `flutter/material.dart` was already imported. But by typing `Widget`, it'd import `flutter/widget.dart` and with a prefix.

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1847

This has been fixed. Upgrading your Dart Code and flutter SDK should fix the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is fixed since I am still having this issue on Android Studio 3.5.